# Checking input is a number in python

Tags: python

I need help, my program is simulating the actions of a dice. I want to an error check to occur checking if the input string is a number and if it isn't I want to ask the question again again until he enters an integer

```
# This progam will simulate a dice with 4, 6 or 12 sides.

import random 

def RollTheDice():

    print("Roll The Dice")
    print()


    NumberOfSides = int(input("Please select a dice with 4, 6 or 12 sides: "))

    Repeat = True 

    while Repeat == True:


        if not NumberOfSides.isdigit() or NumberOfSides not in ValidNumbers:
            print("You have entered an incorrect value")
            NumberOfSides = int(input("Please select a dice with 4, 6 or 12 sides")

        print()
        UserScore = random.randint(1,NumberOfSides)
        print("{0} sided dice thrown, score {1}".format (NumberOfSides,UserScore))

        RollAgain = input("Do you want to roll the dice again? ")


        if RollAgain == "No" or RollAgain == "no":
            print("Have a nice day")
            Repeat = False

        else:
            NumberOfSides = int(input("Please select a dice with 4, 6 or 12 sides: "))
```

Comment: are you using python2 or python3?

Comment: I understand this is one of your first python program, but please dont write in Python like it's C....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a commenter disliked my first answer with `try:` `except ValueError` and the OP asked about how to use `isdigit`, that's how you can do it:

```
valid_numbers = [4, 6, 12]
while repeat:
    number_of_sides = 0      
    while number_of_sides not in valid_numbers:
          number_of_sides_string = input("Please select a dice with 4, 6 or 12 sides: ")
          if (not number_of_sides_string.strip().isdigit() 
              or int(number_of_sides_string) not in valid_numbers):
              print ("please enter one of", valid_numbers)
          else:
              number_of_sides = int(number_of_sides_string)
    # do things with number_of_sides
```

the interesting line is `not number_of_sides_string.strip().isdigit()`. Whitespace at both ends of the input string is removed by `strip`, as a convenience. Then, `isdigit()` checks if the full string consists of numbers.

In your case, you could simply check

```
 if not number_of_sides_string not in ['4', '6', '12']:
     print('wrong')
```

but the other solution is more general if you want to accept any number.

As an aside, the [Python coding style guidelines](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommend lowercase underscore-separated variable names.

Comment: I don't like the use of exception handling for flow control here.  Much rather a call to something like `text.isdigit()`

Comment: it handles input with leading or trailing blanks, though. " 12".isdigit() is False

Comment: I know, I'm just wondering if `text.strip().isdigit()` really is more readable than the try-except.

Comment: okay if iff i use the 'isdigit()' function how do i put that into my code

Comment: i tried your code but it doesn't work can you just give me the whole code

Comment: Sorry, I won't write your program. I will help you doing it, though. First try to write a function that manages the user input. That is the code I already provided in my answer. In your main code you can then call the function in the place where you need the value.

Comment: you build your code from parts small enough to understand. Have you written the `get_number_of_sides` function? Then write a `make_pass_at_dicing` function that does a single pass through "getting the number of sides", "throw dice", "print result". After that, build a loop that uses that function, and then checks if the user want to go again.

Answer (score 1):

Capture the string in a variable, say `text`.  Then do `if text.isdigit()`.

Comment: If you want to be more forgiving to user input, you can `strip()` the input first.

Answer (score 0):

Make a function out of:

```
while NumberOfSides != 4 and NumberOfSides != 6 and NumberOfSides != 12:
    print("You have selected the wrong sided dice")
    NumberOfSides = int(input("Please select a dice with 4, 6 or 12 sides: "))
```

And call it when you want to get input. You should also give an option to quit e.g. by pressing 0. Also you should try catch for invalid number. There is an exact [example in Python doc](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions). Note that input always try to parse as a number and will rise an exception of it's own.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [type method](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#type).

```
my_number = 4
if type(my_number) == int:
    # do something, my_number is int
else:
    # my_number isn't a int. may be str or dict or something else, but not int
```

Or more «pythonic» [isinstance method](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
my_number = 'Four'
if isinstance(my_number, int):
    # do something
raise Exception("Please, enter valid number: %d" % my_number)
```